# Compute the count of unique values in vector of sorted vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, binary-search-tree, frequency, stdmap

I have an object of type `std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>` called `v`, where each subvector (each `std::vector<size_t>`) is sorted. I would like to compute a count of how many times each unique `size_t` of `v` is found. I was thinking about using a `std::map<size_t, size_t>` and do something like

```
int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> v = {
        {4, 10, 12, 18, 20, 28, 34},
        {4, 12, 18, 20, 28},
        {4, 17, 18, 20, 28},
        {4, 17, 18, 20, 28, 37}
    };


    std::map<size_t, size_t> counts;
    for (const auto& a : v)
    {
        for (const auto& b : a)
        {
            auto it = counts.lower_bound(b);
            if (it != counts.end() && !(counts.key_comp()(b, it->first)))
            {
                // mut already exist
                ++(it->second);
            } else
            {
                // mut is new
                counts.insert(it, std::map<size_t, size_t>::value_type(b, 1));
            }
        }   
    }

    for (auto it = counts.begin() ; it != counts.end() ; ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
}
```

, which outputs

```
4: 4
10: 1
12: 2
17: 2
18: 4
20: 4
28: 4
34: 1
37: 1
```

as expected.

In practice, the values are uniformly distributed between 0 and 4e9 hence pushing me into using a `std::map` instead of a `std::vector`. If a value is present in one vector it increases the probably for this value to be found again and again in successive vectors hence making insertions relatively rare compared to incrementation of already inserted values. Also, subparts of vectors tend to be identical.

Is there a better technique? For example, when computing `lower_bound`, it would be faster to make use of the point of insertion of the previous element as elements are sorted. Something like,

```
    for (const auto& a : v)
    {
        MapType::iterator it = a.begin();
        for (const auto& b : a)
        {
            auto it = counts.lower_bound(it, b); // Use `it` to avoid searching in elements that precedes its position
            
            // etc..
        }   
    }
```

, however I don't think [std::map::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) can use a `from` iterator.

Comment: Why so many people try to implement counting with `std::map` using `find()` `lower_bound()` etc when there is classical one liner using `operator[]` ?

Comment: @Slava I used a `map` instead of a `vector` because my values range between 0 and 4e9 (explained in the paragraph starting with `In practice`). I used small values to make an easily readable example.

Comment: And? what difference does it make for this code `for (const auto& a : v) for (const auto& b : a) counts[b]++;` ?

Comment: Hashing all the counts would take up a lot of RAM (and maybe a lot of time to allocate). Your `std::vector<uint32_t> counts` would take about 8GB!

Comment: I understand why you are using `std::map` (though `std::unordered_map` would work faster IMHO) I do not understand multiple line with `lower_bound` conditions etc when `std::map::operator[]` precisely designed for such cases and to work as one liner.

Comment: Because I felt like I would need to perform two binary search, one to figure if the element exists and one to insert it or increment it. Maybe it is just me not understanding what `++counts[b]` would do if `b` is not already in the map.

Comment: Right, nobody novadays try to bother to look into documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at especially into example.

Comment: Oh I did not see  `++counts[b]` in the example! Ok, that largely simplify the code.  Thanks. Do you have any idea on how to take advantage of the fact that the subvectors of `v` are already sorted?

Comment: How many subvectors you usually have?

Answer (score 0):

I present one way to reuse the point of insertion. I am using the fact that insertions are rare.

I would use a sorted vector of pairs as the MapType.

```cpp
typedef std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> MapType;
```

Assuming the vectors are sorted according to a `key_comp` functor. You can then build a Compare functor for your MapType (here I am using a lambda expression to do it).

```cpp
auto comp = [&](std::pair<size_t, size_t>& p1, std::pair<size_t, size_t> const& p2)
    {
        return key_comp(p1.first,p2.first);
    };
```

Now, for every vector in `v`, you can reuse your past insertion points because you know that elements are sorted.

Here is the full code

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> MapType;

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> v = {
        {4, 10, 12, 18, 20, 28, 34},
        {4, 12, 18, 20, 28},
        {4, 17, 18, 20, 28},
        {4, 17, 18, 20, 28, 37}
    };

    auto key_comp = [](std::size_t v1, std::size_t v2) {
        return v1 < v2;
    };

    auto comp = [&](std::pair<size_t, size_t>& p1, std::pair<size_t, size_t> const& p2)
    {
        return key_comp(p1.first,p2.first);
    };


    MapType counts;
    for (const auto& a : v)
    {
        auto it = counts.begin();
        for (const auto& b : a)
        {
            // You can start from it instead of counts.begin() because vector a is sorted
            it = std::lower_bound(it, counts.end(), MapType::value_type(b, 1), comp);
            if (it != counts.end() && !(key_comp(b, it->first)))
            {
                // mut already exist
                ++(it->second);
            } else
            {
                // mut is new
                // Insertion may invalidate iterators so you need to reassign it
                it = counts.insert(it, MapType::value_type(b, 1));
            }
        }   
    }

    for (auto it = counts.begin() ; it != counts.end() ; ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
4: 4
10: 1
12: 2
17: 2
18: 4
20: 4
28: 4
34: 1
37: 1
```

Compiler explorer link : https://godbolt.org/z/zoY7KG

Answer (score 0):

This need to be tested for performance, but assuming that amount of vectors is significantly smaller than numbers in them this method may work faster:

```
using szvec = std::vector<size_t>;
using range = std::pair<szvec::const_iterator,szvec::const_iterator>;

const std::vector<szvec> v = {
    {4, 10, 12, 18, 20, 28, 34},
    {4, 12, 18, 20, 28},
    {4, 17, 18, 20, 28},
    {4, 17, 18, 20, 28, 37}
};

// we use greater so iterator with smallest value will be on top of queue
auto sort_range = []( const range &r1, const range &r2 ) { 
    return *(r1.first) > *(r2.first);
};
std::priority_queue<range,std::vector<range>,decltype(sort_range)> q( sort_range );

// we assume all vectors are not empty on start
// otherwise we need to check for empty range before pushing
for( const auto &vec : v ) q.push( std::make_pair( vec.cbegin(), vec.cend() ) );
std::vector<std::pair<size_t,size_t>> counters;
while( !q.empty() ) {
    auto r = q.top();
    q.pop();
    if( counters.empty() || counters.back().first != *(r.first) ) 
        counters.emplace_back( *(r.first), 1 );
    else 
        counters.back().second++;
    if( ++r.first != r.second ) q.push( r );
}

for( const auto &p : counters ) 
    std::cout << p.first << ":" << p.second << std::endl;
```

So idea is to have iterators to different vectors sorted by value they point to and count the same values passing over iterators rather than process each vector separately.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/RQpBUz)